# Finger IK/FK not working properly

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to rig my character for animation but I can not figure out why my fingers aren't moving properly. They bend and twist unnaturally. I have weight painted the mesh, but I still can't get the fingers to move like a natural hand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbgfYZLmnKiBVxWfa1WqsdUeqW77p8pf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if you are saying that the finger are not moving in direction according to your player. then you can press any axis x, y, or z twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give some weight corrections, see the weight of this bone, it should not influence the last phalanx:

[image]

You need to reassign the vertex groups correctly, either in *Weight Paint* mode, or with the vertex groups in the *Properties panel > Object Data*. You'll find these bones on this layer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So the weight painting for the fingers should look more like what i have here? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rT0ZQvuWdKzWLwYx-Gr3XO8Q8prKcfU1?usp=sharing

Comment: yes that's it exactly

Comment: Thank you! it now works perfectly! i'll be sure to do that for the other fingers.